# Manually Select Driver (AHCI/SATA Drive)

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, sata

I am wondering if there is a way to bypass the default driver when using a SATA Host Bus Adapter (I want it to use my LKM). The other way of doing this is black listing the default driver so mine automatically takes over, but that restricts the hardware I can use. (It still needs to see its boot drives! I just want it to ignore my specific external SATA Controller so the OS doesn't see it.)

Any ideas?